# MongoDB JS Script only single loop is run

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Im using the following script in order to generate test objects in my db.

```
var numberOfTeams = 3;
var membersPerTeam = 1;

function generateMembers() {
    var arr = [];
    for (i =0 ;i < membersPerTeam; i++) {
        var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1).toString();
        var isAdmin = false;
        if (i ==0 ) {
            isAdmin = true;
        }
        arr.push({
            "memberId": randomNumber,
            "admin": isAdmin,
            "name": "member" + randomNumber ,
            "email" : "member" + randomNumber + "@test.com"
        });
    }
    return arr
}

for (var i =0; i<numberOfTeams; i++) {
    db.team.insert({
        "teamName": "test-team-generated" + i,
        "members": generateMembers(),
        "credits" : NumberInt(5000),
        "maxTeamSize": NumberInt(membersPerTeam)
    })
}
```

The problem is that after a single loop, the script will exit. Im looking for a way to set all the values inserted as Int's and to have the loop run for as long as the `numberOfTeams` value is set to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a nested loop in your code which should not be there since within a loop you are calling a function `generateMembers()` that has another loop.
You need to separate the calls in such a way that you populate your variables before running the insert operation. You can also insert an array of documents with a single operation.

The following example refactors the code:

```
function generateMembers(membersPerTeam) {
    var arr = [];
    for (i =0 ;i < membersPerTeam; i++) {
        var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1).toString();
        var isAdmin = false;
        if (i ==0 ) {
            isAdmin = true;
        }
        arr.push({
            "memberId": randomNumber,
            "admin": isAdmin,
            "name": "member" + randomNumber ,
            "email" : "member" + randomNumber + "@test.com"
        });
    }
    return arr
}

var docs = [],
    membersPerTeam = 3,
    members = generateMembers(membersPerTeam);

for (var i =0; i<numberOfTeams; i++) {
    docs.push({
        "teamName": "test-team-generated" + i,
        "members": members,
        "credits" : NumberInt(5000),
        "maxTeamSize": NumberInt(membersPerTeam)
    });
}

db.team.insert(docs)
```